# Excel formula to find out how many times any of specified strings occurs in a given range

Tags: excel-formula

I have list of strings. Every string is in different row. I need to find out how many times any of specified strings occurs in a given range. Any of those strings can also occurs more than once. How could I solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABmd.png)

I have tried the following formula `=SUM(COUNTIF(AS11:AS21,{"aa",bb",cc"...})` (... in context mean the of possible strings).

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.statology.org/excel-count-occurrences/

Answer (score 0):

1. First get a list of unique values with the Excel function "=UNIQUE"
2. With the Excel function "=COUNTIF" you can then Count the Values with help of the Unique Values

Formula in B2:

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B24)
```

Formulaa in E2

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B24;D2)
```

[image: Printscreen from my Excel]

Comment: Just a suggestion--most of the questions here are still from pre-O365 users, so it's usually best to ask first before proposing an O365-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `SUM(COUNTIF())`, you *just* want the 'SUMIF()'.

In your sample image, if you put `=COUNTIF(AS$11:AS$23, AQ11)` you should get the count of "aa" instances.  Just copy or fill that formula down and you should be all set.